# Image not served correctly

Tags: html, image, gimp

I created an image in gimp and attempted to use it in a web page.
my source code:
 `<p><img src="img/ad3.png" alt="ad2" /></p>`
The image does not show up in either  FF or chrome.

The source code in the browser has a class added:

`<img class="edvocigqzrpabapyavku" alt="ad2" src="img/ad3.png">`

in the network panel in chrome it says the image has a 307 redirect to :

`data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAACklEQVR4nGMAAQAABQABDQottAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==`

any idea why that might be?

There is an image right before it that does load properly and the paths are all correct.

The only difference between the two images is that the one that does load is a graphic created from scratch in gimp and the one that does not load is created from pasting into gimp.

Comment: That's probably what the file contains. Try saving your image as a PNG file instead of a data URI and see if that helps.

Comment: its not the browser, its an apache header

Comment: whats the mime type?

Comment: Looks like a PNG to me. 1x1px transparent RGB. ~ http://jsfiddle.net/tLdgknug/

Comment: It is a png file created in gimp!!

Comment: What does the HTML look like, **exactly**?

Comment: <p><img src="img/ad3.png" alt="ad2" /></p>

Comment: @HueMan that doesn't look anything like the code in your question

Comment: i know , the image does not show up in ff or chrome. Fire bug shows nothing about this image and in chromes dev tools it says there is a 307 redirect and the location is the uri above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recreated the image with PS Elements and it works just fine.
Seems to be a gimp issue.

Comment: I doubt that. What did you do in GIMP to create that file, and is this test page online somewhere for us to try?

Comment: Images that with pasting from another picture in gimp would not load over network . they would display in the browser locally though and the paths were correct. I recreated the same image in PS and it worked.

Comment: And I want to see that site and image file and be able to examine it, if possible.

Comment: I believe i overwrote it

Answer (score 0):

Does webpage refer to your webpage in your hosting? Or a webpage in your computer?

Also, what is the folder structure?

Can you try this?

`<p><img src="../img/ad3.png" alt="ad2" /></p>`

Its probably that the file doesnt exist in the location that you are linking to.

Comment: The file does exist. when i view it on my computer it does load and from my server it doesn't